# Updated Git on Mac & old version still showing

Tags: git, homebrew

I've had Git on my Mac for a while (previously downloaded and installed it from the Git website some time ago). Today I decided I wanted to update Git - I ended up installing homebrew and running **$brew install git** which all seemed to work fine.

The problem I have is that **$git --version** is still showing the older version (git version 2.21.0). So I think I've got 2 Git installations on my machine and it's using the old one?

**$which git** gives: **/usr/local/bin/git**

**$echo $PATH** gives: **/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin**

I'm no expert, but this looks really wrong?!

From poking around in the file structure I find the following folder, which looks like the new install of Git: **/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.30.1**

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this mess? Much appreciated :)

Comment: Does `which -a git` give any clues?

Comment: When I run `which -a git` it gives me: **/usr/local/bin/git** and then
**/usr/bin/git** ...I'm not quite sure what to do with this however?

Comment: The brew guys kept reshuffling the places that binaries landed. I got a bit annoyed at that. Then they changed to putting them all in `/usr/local/bin`, which was good. It looks like they've gone back to shuffling them about. I haven't updated the various brew files on my Mac in over a year at this point, so I have not had a chance to get re-annoyed. :-)

Comment: In any case, you can choose from various fixes, each with various drawbacks: you can alter your `$PATH` setting to add more places to look (remember that the shell tries them in order, and runs whichever one runs first); you can move "cellared" stuff elsewhere (but remember that builds might have paths compiled in which might defeat this); you can run explicit variants by invoking `/usr/local/cellar/git/2.30.1/git`; and so on.

Comment: @torek thank you...I will have a further play and see what I can come up with...maybe I'll start by trying to invoke explicit variants first to check what's actually there...and then maybe alter my path...I'm not so experienced with these sorts of things so it's a bit trial and error!

Answer (score 9):

In my case, the changes in $PATH settings didn't work. Always got the Apple version when doing git --version.

What worked for me was: `brew link --overwrite git`

After that, I got the version of brew installed git.